# Retopologize high poly geometry-nodes-generated shape to low poly

Tags: geometry-nodes, topology, optimization, retopology, polycount

I have this geometry that I generated using geometry nodes. It is super high poly and I need to reduce the number of polygons to as low as possible. What would be the most optimal way to do this? I already tried the remesh built-in feature with no luck. I started manual retopology but since the shape is pretty repetetive I figure there should be a better way to do this.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The most reasonable approach is to modify the geometry nodes setup to produce less dense topology. I doubt there's any generalized approach other than remeshing... In your case all we can see is that you have "steps", which is face loops of alternating surfaces, so maybe you can split edges by angle close to $90°$, then you could convert the mesh to curves, resample the curves and loft them. Lofting will be easy where the curves go from top to bottom, but near the left/right edges it gets harder...